# Generate sugestions by genre id

Tags: laravel, model, recommendation-engine

Using laravel 7 and pivot tables i have something like this:

Model: show

```
public function genres()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\ShowGenre');
}
```

Model: ShowGenre

```
public function shows()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Show', 'show_show_genre')->orderBy('name', 'asc');
}
```

In mysql database i have show_genres where i put my show_id and genre_id. So i want to create something like suggestion based.

At bottom my page i want to display 5 random tv shows that have same genre. Some tv shows have multiple genres so how can i display that and limit it with suma 5.

Comment: If a show can have more than one genre is it picking shows from any of the genres or just one genre

Comment: From any of genres, and limit it on 5. It's better sugestion than only from one genre of tv show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`show_show_genre` should have `show_id` and `show_genre_id` because `show_show_genre` is pivot table. `show_genres` is not pivot table since it is genre's table as described in code. Also, you don't need to set `show_show_genre` in return statement since Laravel will automatically recognize it's pivot table.
Try something like this:

```
$show = Show::findOrFail($id);

$featuredShows = Show::whereHas('genres', function ($query) use ($show) {
    $query->whereIn('show_genres.id', $show->genres()->pluck('id')->toArray());
})->where('id', '!=' , $show->id)->with(['genres'])->inRandomOrder()->limit(5)->get();
```

Comment: That is giving me a random genre with random tv shows. Actually i have single tv show where i display like "Grey's Anatomy" it is drama and comedia, i want random 5 shows where is drama or comedia genre, to use both genre creating random 5 tv shows with some of that genres from show which is opened in browser.

Comment: Can you update your question with controller's method code to help me better understand how you get that single tv show because nothing in question post told how it's chosen. @PooX

Comment: It's just Show::FindOrFail($id); I think thet there where you put $query->where(['show_genres.id'] that need to change to get all genres from show_show_genre where is show_id and by thet genres to find every other tv show that have some of that genres. :/

Comment: That changes lot in your question and shad some new light, let me check now.

Comment: Thanks, now this works. Just need some fix, $show->genres()->pluck.. i remove (), so $show->genres->pluck.. then it works perfectly, just like i wanted at begining. Also thank you for showing some usefull way to get data in laravel, that will help me for future things. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: I am not sure pluck would work as property. It's method. Watch out that you'd get some not easily recognised error in the future because of that. `pluck()` is method. What happens if you use as method? Or, try to remove it fully from chain.

Comment: I think that you don't understead me about that what i remove. I get genres from tv show with $show->genres, not $show->genres(), if i have () than i have error, without it i can use foreach($show->genres as $item), not ($show->genres() as $item). Pluck('id') that is unchanged. Just at genres i remove (), don't know why is this like that but it's work on that way. Thank you so much for your time and help. :D

Comment: Maybe I don't (understand; although I know what you are saying to me), I am just also confused why it didn't work way how I wrote. But I am glad if you've used it as base solution. Differences between eloquent members (property and method): `$show->genres` will return collection while `$show->genres()` will return query builder. Latter is used in chaining for example `$show->genres()->where(['active' => 1])->get()`. Or also `$show->genres` is equal to `$show->genres()->get()`. :) Happy coding. Also, check [here](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices), it will help you in code